# The Partition of a Large Triangle into Smaller Triangles Induction Proof

Tags: geometry, induction

I'm stuck on proving "if $n$ points are placed inside a triangle, and non-intersecting lines are drawn connecting the 3 vertices of the triangle and the points within it to partition the triangle into smaller triangles, then the maximum number of triangles resulting is $2n+1$.

I drew out what it would look like with 1 point, and so proving for first point is easy, but I'm unsure how to progress from there, so could anyone prove this for me with the principle of mathematical induction?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:

If you have $n$ points and $2n+1$ triangles and you add a point, this point will be in one of these triangles.

Comment: I'm confused, how do I use this hint in the proof?

Comment: You can divide the triangle where the new point is into three new triangles. You can not make more lines because they can not intersect. So the new point "destroys" one triangle and "generates" three.

Comment: So how would this work in the inductive step of the proof?

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that in the end the given triangle $T$ is triangulated. Counting the exterior of $T$ as another triangular face we then have a triangulation of $S^2$. We now invoke Euler's theorem:
$$v+f=e+2\ .$$
Since all faces are triangles we in addition have $3f=2e$, so that we obtain $2v+2f=3f+4$, or
$$f=2v-4=2(3+n)-4=2n+2\ .$$
It follows that the number of small triangles in $T$ is even **equal** to $2n+1$.